# Shared namespace not being recognized in Blazor Server project

Tags: .net-core, blazor, .net-core-3.0, blazor-server-side

I am trying to build a Blazor Server project that I have cloned from a repo. I am getting the message in the Output window of Visual Studio 2019 that the Shared namespace does not exist. The Shared namespace is created in the Blazor template and was not something I added to the project. This also happens if I create a new project and try to run it. Others on my team are able to clone this repo and run it. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise edition and also the Dotnet 3.0.1 framework. The only thing I can think that might be the difference is that I updated my VS 2019 to 16.3.10, but even after uninstalling and reinstalling, I have the same issue. I know I have read some things about mismatching of VS and Dotnet core framework SDK versions causing issues but not sure if this is the case here.

Comment: I would check what versions of VS and .NET your team members are using against yours. `dotnet --version`

Comment: We checked `dotnet --info` and they were the same versions.

Comment: Only other suggestion if the versions are indentical to your other team members is to clean out the app and try again. Remove the `obj` and `bin` folders and rebuild

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this issue by rebuilding the project after clearing Nuget Caches.

Path: Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> General -> Clear all Nuget Cache(s).